# Publishing an sbt scala project to Artifactory with the env vars

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

What I have is this.

I have defined in sbt my publish task which publishes to artifactory. Im running it in a Jenkins job as a shell build step.

What I would like to do is to include all the environment information that the Jenkins Artifactory plugin includes when it deploys. I dont know if I should it add it to sbt or if there is some way of configuring the Plugin to use sbt but do the publishing himself.

Answer (score 8):

Currently there is no integration for `sbt` and `Artifactory Jenkins` plugin, what you can do is to use the [Generic deployment feature of the plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringGeneric%28Freestyle%29Builds). The plugin will upload as part of the deployment a build info json object with some of the system and environment variables.

Because the plugin doesn't record the actual build process
then all the run time goodies will be missed but you could inject them by using `buildInfo.property.*` - All properties starting with this prefix will be added to the root properties of the `build-info`.

Comment: I tried that at first, using the Generic deployment feature. The problem that I was having was that I could not find a way of setting a groupId, artifactId or version for the build. It was being sent as single tar.gz. Assuming this is somehow possible, then what you are suggesting is to include buildInfo.property.* in the "deployment properties" section of the plugin?

Comment: conversely, is there any way of injecting the buildinfo.property.* vars via sbt?

Comment: If your target is to generate maven compatible coordinates, you have two options - 1. just arrange them in Maven canonical layout. 2. use mappings to control the final layout in Artifactory (again, arrange them according to Maven standards)

Comment: Would be great to see Artifactory Jenkins & SBT plugins!